# Changing String to String Array Then Converting String Array to Integer Array VB.NET

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, integer

I have these current values in which I want the numbers alone in an array called arrResult(). I successfully get the numbers to the form I want. I then want to transfer the variables from the string aVariables and store them in arrResult(). I then want to convert arrResult() from a string array to an integer array but I don't know how to go about this.

```
Dim variables As String = "+0.9716 mA,+0.9699 mA,+0.9686 mA,+0.9655 mA,+0.9650 mA,+0.9636 mA,+0.9618 mA,+0.9607 mA,+0.9581 mA,+0.9575 mA,+0.9562 mA,+0.9549 mA,+0.9523 mA"
Dim arrResult() As String = variables.Split(",")
Dim plusVariables As String = variables.Replace("+", "")
Dim mVariables As String = plusVariables.Replace("m", "")
Dim aVariables As String = mVariables.Replace("A", "")
MsgBox(String.Join(vbCrLf, aVariables.Replace(" ", "").Split(",")))
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, neither from your description nor from the code. An array of `0.9716`, `0.9699` etc? A string with `"0.9716,0.9699,etc"`?

Comment: How exactly does it make sense to create an `Integer` array for numbers with 4 decimal places?

Comment: Now and for all your code turn on Option Strict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally recommend staying away from VB Runtime functions, i.e. functions that are members of the modules in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace, but there are specific scenarios where they can add value. The `Val` function is generally garbage but the behaviour that makes it garbage is useful in this specific scenario:

```vb
Dim text = "+0.9716 mA,+0.9699 mA,+0.9686 mA,+0.9655 mA,+0.9650 mA,+0.9636 mA,+0.9618 mA,+0.9607 mA,+0.9581 mA,+0.9575 mA,+0.9562 mA,+0.9549 mA,+0.9523 mA"
Dim numbers = text.Split(","c).Select(Function(s) Val(s)).ToArray()

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers))
```

Output:

```
0.9716
0.9699
0.9686
0.9655
0.965
0.9636
0.9618
0.9607
0.9581
0.9575
0.9562
0.9549
0.9523
```

The `Val` function reads a `Double` from the start of a `String`, so the units at the end of each part are automatically trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative might be using Linq to get only digits o punctuation characters:

```
    Dim variables As String = "+0.9716 mA,+0.9699 mA,+0.9686 mA,+0.9655 mA,+0.9650 mA,+0.9636 mA,+0.9618 mA,+0.9607 mA,+0.9581 mA,+0.9575 mA,+0.9562 mA,+0.9549 mA,+0.9523 mA"
    Dim arrDoubles() As String = variables.Split(","c).Select(Function(s) New String(s.Where(Function(el) Char.IsDigit(el) OrElse Char.IsPunctuation(el)).ToArray)).ToArray

    Debug.WriteLine(Strings.Join(arrDoubles, vbCrLf))
```

Comment: I made an edit to your answer, thinking you got the arguments to `String.Join` the wrong way around. I then realised that you were calling `Strings.Join` rather than `String.Join`. I'd stay away from that VB Runtime function anyway but, if you do use it, it's rather unusual to qualify it. It was only the fact that the syntax colouring was different to my code that made me realise.

Comment: Happen to every one especially in “quick mode”. All right bro.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jmcilhinney that nasty old `Val` works in this instance. Here is what it would like without `Val`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lst As New List(Of Double)
    Dim variables As String = "+0.9716 mA,+0.9699 mA,+0.9686 mA,+0.9655 mA,+0.9650 mA,+0.9636 mA,+0.9618 mA,+0.9607 mA,+0.9581 mA,+0.9575 mA,+0.9562 mA,+0.9549 mA,+0.9523 mA"
    Dim splits = variables.Split(","c)
    For Each s In splits
        Dim Number = CDbl(s.Split(" "c)(0))
        lst.Add(Number)
    Next
    For Each d In lst
        Debug.Print(d.ToString("0.###0"))
    Next
End Sub
```